# Duplicating sprites with the same function

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, python-3.7

I have been making a `pygame` game where 2 players try and hit a ball into a net(a simplified version of the code below). I have added boost pads where your boost seconds go up when you collect a boost pad. I want several of these all around the map in different locations, but without copying and pasting the code several times. A previous question of mine ([How to implement a timeout/cooldown after collision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52553011/how-to-implement-a-timeout-cooldown-after-collision?noredirect=1#comment92045417_52553011)) shows how to do it with `self`, but whilst using `classes`. I am not very experienced with python and have not taught myself how do some less interesting things(for me) such as how to use classes correctly. I would like someone to duplicate the boostpad, whilst keeping the code in the same format it is in now(without classes because I am rubbish at python :( ) and not copying and psting the code several times. Is this possible?

```
import pygame
from pygame.math import Vector2
import time, datetime
import sys

pygame.font.init()
pygame.init()


WIDTH = 1150
HEIGHT = 800
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()


REDCAR_ORIGINAL = pygame.Surface((50, 30), pygame.SRCALPHA)
pygame.draw.polygon(
    REDCAR_ORIGINAL, (255, 0, 0), [(0, 30), (50, 20), (50, 10), (0, 0)])
redangle = 180
redcar = pygame.transform.rotate(REDCAR_ORIGINAL, redangle)
redangle = 180
booster = pygame.Surface((50, 150), pygame.SRCALPHA)
booster.fill(pygame.color.Color("yellow"))
booster1 = booster.get_rect(topleft=(0, 340))
boostermask = pygame.mask.from_surface(booster)


redspeed = 5

dx = 0
dy = 0
x = 800
y = 500
redscore = 0
boostpadtimer = 3


pos_red = Vector2(x,y)
vel_red = Vector2(-redspeed,0)
redrect = redcar.get_rect(center=pos_red)
redangle = 180
redcar = pygame.transform.rotate(REDCAR_ORIGINAL, redangle)
pos_blue = Vector2(275,300)


# Masks.
mask_red = pygame.mask.from_surface(redcar)


def redboosts():
    global vel_red
    global timer
    global dt
    if timer > 0:
        vel_red.scale_to_length(10)
        timer -= dt



def slowdown():
    vel_red.scale_to_length(5)






timer = 3
dt = 1
boost_recieved = False
timerr = False









run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
          if event.key == pygame.K_r:
              # Reset the car to the start position.
              redangle = 180
              redcar = pygame.transform.rotate(REDCAR_ORIGINAL, redangle)
              pos_red = Vector2(800, 500)
              vel_red = Vector2(-redspeed, 0)
              redrect = redcar.get_rect(center=pos_red)
              mask_red = pygame.mask.from_surface(redcar)
          #elif event.key == pygame.K_s:
          #    vel_blue.scale_to_length(2)
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                vel_red.scale_to_length(5)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
              vel_red.scale_to_length(5)


    #print(boostpadtimer)
    print(timer)

    if boost_recieved:
        if boostpadtimer == 3:
            timer += 3
            booster.fill(pygame.color.Color("grey"))
            boost_recieved = False
    if timerr:
        boostpadtimer -= dt

    if boostpadtimer <= 0:
        timerr = False
        boostpadtimer = 3

    if boostpadtimer == 3:
        booster.fill(pygame.color.Color("yellow"))




    #if timer < 0:
    #    timer = 3


    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
              redangle += 5
              vel_red.rotate_ip(-5)
              redcar = pygame.transform.rotate(REDCAR_ORIGINAL, redangle)
              redrect = redcar.get_rect(center=redrect.center)
              # We need a new mask after the rotation.
              mask_red = pygame.mask.from_surface(redcar)
    elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
              redangle -= 5
              vel_red.rotate_ip(5)
              redcar = pygame.transform.rotate(REDCAR_ORIGINAL, redangle)
              redrect = redcar.get_rect(center=redrect.center)
              mask_red = pygame.mask.from_surface(redcar)


    if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
              redboosts()
    if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
              vel_red.scale_to_length(2)
    if keys[pygame.K_s]:
              vel_blue.scale_to_length(2)

    if y <0:
        y = 10
    if y > 450:
        y = 440
    if x > 480:
        x = 470


    if redrect.top < 0 and vel_red.y < 0:
        redrect.top = 0
        pos_red = Vector2(redrect.center)
    elif redrect.bottom > screen.get_height() and vel_red.y > 0:
        redrect.bottom = screen.get_height()
        pos_red = Vector2(redrect.center)
    if redrect.left < 0 and vel_red.x < 0:
        redrect.left = 0
        pos_red = Vector2(redrect.center)
    elif redrect.right > screen.get_width() and vel_red.x > 0:
        redrect.right = screen.get_width()
        pos_red = Vector2(redrect.center)


    pos_red += vel_red
    redrect.center = pos_red


    offset = booster1[0] - redrect[0], booster1[1] - redrect[1]
    collectboost = mask_red.overlap(boostermask, offset)

    if timer <= 0:
        timer = 0
        vel_red.scale_to_length(5)
        slowdown()

    if collectboost:
        boost_recieved = True
        timerr = True


    screen.fill((50,200,50))
    screen.blit(redcar, redrect)
    screen.blit(booster, booster1)


    pygame.display.flip()
    dt = clock.tick(60)/1000
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Sorry to break it to ya, but you gonna need to use classes. OOP (Object Oriented Progamming) is this essentially - using classes means you can easily add 'instances' of objects without having to duplicate lines of code. It also means later on, while in game, jump pads can be easily added

Comment: I think you can, why not? Though you will need to duplicate processess, variables and detections, also nesting loops within loops within loops (which slows down the program sometimes). Though at the end, the bulk of your code will make it hard to debug, and/or to read. Learning how to use classes will make it soooo easy to do this without as much lines of code.

Comment: I'd recommend using classes/OOP as well, but you could also use lists or dictionaries as a representation for the boost pads, put them into a `boost_pads` list and use for loops to update and draw them, e.g. `{'image': booster, 'rect': booster.get_rect(topleft=(0, 340)), 'timer': 3, 'mask': boostermask}`. Take a look at [Program Arcade Games](http://programarcadegames.com/) (chapter 12 and 13) to get started with classes/OOP, sprites and sprite groups.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll be sure to check all these things out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question: I don't think what you want is possible without using classes.

They are a great way to implement things like your boostpad.

Simple example:

```
class BoostPad(pygame.Surface):

    def __init__(color='red',time_value=3,x_size=0,y_size=0,size_or_position=(0,0)):
        self.color = color
        self.time_value=time_value
        self.time = time_value

        super(pygame.Surface, self).__init__((x_size, y_size, pygame.SRCALPHA)
        self.fill(pygame.color.Color(color))
        # Not sure if this is a size or position
        self.size_or_position = self.get_rect(topleft=size_or_position)
        self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(booster)


    def set_color(color):
        self.fill(pygame.color.Color(color))


    def boost_triggered(self):
        if self.time is self.time_value:
            self.time = 0
            self.set_color('grey')
            return self.time_value


    def add_time(self, dt):
        self.time += dt
        if self.time is self.time_value:
            self.set_color(self.color)
```

etc and so on.

I'm not entirely sure I can make out how your game runs as I've never used pygame but the application should be similar.